Excel, is there a formula to fill in a cell if text is present in another cell otherwise empty if there is no text in the referred cell?
What I am trying to do is something like this below:
=IF($B11= ,"text is present","")
where after $B11= I indicate that the value is any text that is present in $B11, if that cell is blank then I want the cell to be left blank.
Is there a way to this using the IF statement?
I want to drag the formula down a column as I need to update a column accordingly.
As an example (suppose the rows are 11 - 14):

in the table above, I expect A11 and A13 to show "text is present" (without the quotes) in the cell and in A12 and A14 I expect the cell to be blank since the value in B12 and B14 is blank.
I have tried using the IF statement but cannot get it to work according to the conditions.

If you want to match any non-empty cell content, not just a string, this should work for you:
=IF($B11<>"" ,"text is present","")


If you only want to filter out text and not pure numbers, you can use:
=IF(ISTEXT($B11), "there's text", "no text")


Or if you want to check text vs numbers vs 'empty':
=IFERROR(IFS(ISTEXT($B11),"Text",ISNUMBER($B11),"Numbers"),"")

